# how to use listview data from another class?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

im working on vb(or c#).
For example, i have a three class with different designs.
Class 1 of the main design has a function that receives data from the equipment, and this function returns the data as an array.
Class 2 of the second design invokes a function in class 1 to store and display the data in the listview.
I want to output and use the data of the listview of the second designer's class in the third designer.
To summarize, class 1 gets data, class 2 calls class 1 and outputs data to listview. Class 3 tries to use class 2's listview data.
Did my intentions pass exactly? I'm sorry I do not English well.
Thank you for your attention! :)

Comment: Firstly, there's no such language as vb(c#).  If you're using VB then you're using VB. If you're using C# then you're using C#.

Comment: As for the question, it would be a mistake to use the data from the `ListView`. A `ListView` is for data display, not data storage.  If you need to use the data elsewhere then you should be storing the original data retrieved from the first class and then passing that on, not pushing it all into a `ListView` and then pulling it all back out again to use elsewhere.

Comment: @jins your class 2 should hold data in raw form (say list of strings) it should use this list to display data on listview and also expose this data to class 3

Comment: i modified 'c#' -> 'or c#'..
this is my meaning :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `class2` should hold data in raw form (say list of strings) it should use this list to display data on `listview` and also expose this data to `class3`

I have created a sample program showing how to do SO!

lets take three forms `Form1`, `Form2`, and `Form3`

`Form1` (class1) : this will hold the actual data, which we need to display on `listview` of `Form2` and also we need to pass this information to `Form3` via `Form2`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Data which need to be shown in list view 
    //and also need to pass to form3 (class3)
    public List<string> Data = new List<string>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Data.Add("item1");
        Data.Add("item2");
    }
    private void btnForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

`Form2` (class 2) : this class will hold data of `Form1` as raw form (here list of string) so it doesn't have to expose entire `listview` to `Form3` .

you see, `form3` just need data, not control on which it is displayed, so better to keep control (`listview`) not accessible by external codes.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 m_form1;
    List<string> m_dataOfListview;
    //exposing row data publically so form3 can use it
    //note that, it is read only, so form3 can only read it. Not modify
    public List<string> DataOfListView
    {
        get { return m_dataOfListview; }
    }
    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_form1 = form1;
    }
    private void btnFetchData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_dataOfListview = m_form1.Data;
        foreach(string data in m_dataOfListview)
            listView1.Items.Add(data);
    }
    private void btnShowForm3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 form3 = new Form3(this);
        form3.Show();
    }
}
```

and at last `Form3` (class 3)

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    Form2 m_form2;
    public Form3(Form2 form2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_form2 = form2;

        //here in this class you can get value of data of listview
        List<string> dataOfListView = form2.DataOfListView;
    }
}
```